# Using XMLHTTPRequest to extract data from Database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, xmlhttprequest

I want to extract some data from the database without refreshing a page. What is the best possible way to do this?

I am using the following XMLHTTPRequest function to get some data (shopping cart items) from `cart.php` file. This file performs various functions based on the `option` value.
For example: `option=1` means get all the shopping cart items. `option=2` means delete all shopping cart items and return string `"Your shopping cart is empty."`. option=3, 4...and so on.

My XHR function:

```
    function getAllCartItems()
    {
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            allCartItems = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            allCartItems=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        allCartItems.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (allCartItems.readyState==4 && allCartItems.status==200)
            {
                document.getElementById("cartmain").innerHTML=allCartItems.responseText;
            }
            else if(allCartItems.readyState < 4)
            {
                 //do nothing
            }
        }
        var linktoexecute = "cart.php?option=1";
        allCartItems.open("GET",linktoexecute,true);
        allCartItems.send();
    }
```

**cart.php** file looks like:

```
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', '123456'); 
    if (!$link)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db('projectdatabase');
    if($option == 1) //get all cart items
    {
        $sql = "select itemid from cart where cartid=".$_COOKIE['cart'].";";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                 echo $row['itemid'];
            }
    }
    else if($option == 2)
    {
            //do something
    }
    else if($option == 3)
    {
            //do something
    }
    else if($option == 4)
    {
            //do something
    }
```

**My Questions:**

1. Is there any other way I can get the data from database without
   refreshing the page?
2. Are there any potential threats (hacking, server utilization,
   performance etc) in my way of doing this thing? I believe a hacker
   can flood my server be sending unnecessary requests using option=1,
   2, 3 etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think a *Denial of Service* attack would be your main concern, here. That concern would be just as valid is `cart.php` were to return HTML. No, exposing a public API for use via AJAX is pretty common practice.

One thing to keep in mind, though, is the ambiguity of both listing and deleting items via the same URL. It would be a good idea to (at the very least) separate those actions (or "methods") into distinct URLs (for example: `/cart/list` and `/cart/clear`).

If you're willing to go a step further, you should consider implementing a "[RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)" API. This would mean, among other things, that methods can only be called using the correct HTTP verb. You've possibly only heard of `GET` and `POST`, but there's also `PUT` and `DELETE`, amongst others. The reason behind this is to make the methods *idempotent*, meaning that they do the same thing again and again, no matter how many times you call them. For example, a `GET` call to `/cart` will always list the contents and a `DELETE` call to `/cart` will always delete all items in the cart.

Although it is probably not practical to write a full REST API for your shopping cart, I'm sure some of the principles may help you build a more robust system.

Some reading material: [A Brief Introduction to REST](http://www.infoq.com/articles/rest-introduction).

Comment: Can you please clarify how RESTful api's reduce my vulnerability to Denial of Service attacks as opposed to using HTTP POST or GET? Reason I ask is I have implemented API's which work with GET or POST and I've been wondering how to make them more secure. Thanks!

Comment: @Manish: they don't, and you *do* use `POST` and `GET`. REST is meant to make your API less ambiguous (more explicit) and to prevent unintended side-effects. How to secure your API depends on what you want to secure it *against* (i.e. do you want access restriction, or protection against flooding?)

Comment: I have access restriction implemented using HSA1. I was wondering about flooding. I read an interesting paper which presented (wish I'd bookmarked) data to suggest that even post was more vulnerable to get.

Answer (score 1):

`Ajax` is the best option for the purpose.

Now sending and receiving data with `Ajax` is done best using `XML`. So use of `Web services` is the recommended option from me. You can use a `SOAP / REST` web service to bring data from a database on request.

You can use this [Link](http://www.w3.org/TR/ws-arch/) to understand more on Webservices.

For the tutorials enough articles are available in the Internet.

Comment: Saying *"AJAX is best done using XML"* is like saying *"it's best to travel anywhere by [amphibian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amphibious_vehicle)"*. Sure, XML has its uses. But sometimes a simpler exchange format, like [JSON](http://www.json.org/), is a better choice. It all depends on the context.

Comment: In other words: don't go by car if you're going next door (10m: you should walk) or to the other side of the planet (16.000km: buy a plane ticket).

Comment: Also, it should be noted that for slow connections, XML uses a lot of bandwidth, while JSON is much lighter.

Answer (score 1):

1. you're using a `XMLHttpRequest` object, so you don't refresh your page (it's AJAX), or there's something you haven't tell
2. if a hacker want to DDOS your website, or your database, he can use any of its page... As long as you don't transfer string between client and server that will be used in your SQL requests, that should be OK
3. I'd warn you about the use of raw text response display. I encourage you to format your response as XML or JSON to correctly locate objects that needs to be inserted into the DOM, and to return an  tag to correctly handle errors (the die("i'm your father luke") won't help any of your user) and to display them in a special area of your web page

Answer (score 1):

First, you should consider separating different parts of your application. Having a general file that performs every other tasks related to carts, violates all sorts of software design principles.

Second, the first vulnerability is SQL injection. You should **NEVER** just concatenate the input to your SQL.

Suppose I posted `1; TRUNCATE TABLE cart;`. Then your SQL would look like:

`select itemid from cart where cartid=1; TRUNCATE TABLE cart;` which first selects the item in question, then ruins your database.

You should write something like this:

```
$item = $_COOKIE['cart'];
$item = preg_replace_all("['\"]", "\\$1", $item);
```

To avoid *refreshing*, you can put a link on your page. Something like, `<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getAllCartItems();">Refresh</a>`

In terms of security, it will always pay to introduce a database layer concerned with just your data, regardless of your business logic, then adding a service layer dependent on the database layer, which would provide facilities to perform business layer actions.

You should also take @PPvG recommendation into note, and -- using Apache's mod_rewrite or other similar facilities -- make your URLs more meaningful.

Another note: try to encapsulate your data in JSON or XML format. I'd recommend the use of `json_encode();` on the server side, and `JSON.parse();` on the client side. This would ensure a secure delivery.